# Nested XML output - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm having some trouble getting the XML result I'm looking for in my SQL query.

I'm using this:

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM(UN_NMBR), 
    (SELECT RTRIM(SUB_UNIT_ID) 
     FOR XML PATH('SUBUNIT'), TYPE),
    (SELECT NEW_STAT, [TIME] 
     FOR XML PATH('STATUS'), TYPE)
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         UN_NMBR, NEW_STAT,
         CONVERT(TIME,STAMP_CHANGE) as 'TIME' 
     FROM 
         Test.SDUPDADM.CADUNTDB2 
     WHERE 
         CFS_NUMBR = '021918-73') u
JOIN
    Test.SDUPDADM.CADSUBDB2 s on s.UNT_NUMBER = u.UN_NMBR
WHERE
    CFS_NUMBR = '021918-73' 
FOR XML PATH('UNIT'), TYPE, ROOT('RUNTIMES')
```

And I get this result:

```
<RUNTIMES>
  <UNIT>501A<SUBUNIT>HB5134</SUBUNIT><STATUS> <NEW_STAT>ON_SCENESTOP</NEW_STAT><TIME>12:13:23</TIME></STATUS></UNIT>
  <UNIT>501A<SUBUNIT>HB5134</SUBUNIT><STATUS><NEW_STAT>CODE4       </NEW_STAT><TIME>12:29:33</TIME></STATUS></UNIT>
  <UNIT>501A<SUBUNIT>HB5134</SUBUNIT><STATUS><NEW_STAT>AVAIL       </NEW_STAT><TIME>12:36:29</TIME></STATUS></UNIT>
  <UNIT>503A<SUBUNIT>HB5910</SUBUNIT><STATUS><NEW_STAT>DISP        </NEW_STAT><TIME>12:13:24</TIME></STATUS></UNIT>
  <UNIT>503A<SUBUNIT>HB5910</SUBUNIT><STATUS><NEW_STAT>EN_ROUTE    </NEW_STAT><TIME>12:13:26</TIME></STATUS></UNIT>
  <UNIT>503A<SUBUNIT>HB5910</SUBUNIT><STATUS><NEW_STAT>ON_SCENE    </NEW_STAT><TIME>12:20:42</TIME></STATUS></UNIT>
  <UNIT>503A<SUBUNIT>HB5910</SUBUNIT><STATUS><NEW_STAT>AVAIL       </NEW_STAT><TIME>12:26:17</TIME></STATUS></UNIT>
</RUNTIMES>
```

But what I really want is this:

```
<RUNTIMES>
   <UNIT>501A
       <SUBUNIT>HB5134
            <STATUS>
                 <NEW_STAT>ON_SCENESTOP</NEW_STAT>
                 <TIME>12:13:23</TIME>
            </STATUS>
            <STATUS>
                 <NEW_STAT>CODE4       </NEW_STAT>
                 <TIME>12:29:33</TIME>
            </STATUS>
            <STATUS>
                 <NEW_STAT>AVAIL       </NEW_STAT>
                 <TIME>12:36:29</TIME>
            </STATUS>
       </SUBUNIT>
   </UNIT>
   <UNIT>503A
       <SUBUNIT>HB5910
            <STATUS>
                 <NEW_STAT>DISP        </NEW_STAT>
                 <TIME>12:13:24</TIME>
            </STATUS>
            <STATUS>
                 <NEW_STAT>EN_ROUTE    </NEW_STAT>
                 <TIME>12:13:26</TIME>
            </STATUS>
            <STATUS>
                 <NEW_STAT>ON_SCENE    </NEW_STAT>
                 <TIME>12:20:42</TIME>
            </STATUS>
            <STATUS>
                 <NEW_STAT>AVAIL       </NEW_STAT>
                 <TIME>12:26:17</TIME>
            </STATUS>
       </SUBUNIT>
   </UNIT>
</RUNTIMES>
```

There must be something off in my nesting. What am I doing wrong in my query?

Comment: You must use correlated sub-queries in connection with `GROUP BY`. You'll find an example in the linked thread...

Comment: Group By did not work for this data set. I figured it out by rewriting the query without the subquery.